# Finding a primitive element of a finite field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(m(x))$, where $m(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. How do I find a primitive element of $F$, i.e., one that generates the nonzero elements of $F$ multiplicatively?

For example, in $\mathbb{F}_{256} = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)$, the element $x+1$ has order $255$, so it is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{256}$.

Comment: This is hard. To see how hard,have a look at this paper: [Finding primitive elements in ﬁnite ﬁelds of small
characteristic](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1206v4.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

There is a more efficient algorithm, but it involves determining the prime factors of p<sup>n</sup>-1, then testing for all combinations of those factors. For GF(256) = GF(2<sup>8</sup>), the prime factors of 256-1 = 255 are: 3, 5, 17. The combinations to test for are 3 x 5 = 15, 3 x 17 = 51, 5 x 17 = 85. There's no need to test for 3 x 5 x 17 = 255, since any element raised to the 255 power = 1.

Let α = a potential candidate for a primitive element, then only the first 3 of the 4 cases below have to be tested:

$\alpha^{15} \bmod (x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1) \neq 1$ 
$\alpha^{51} \bmod (x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1) \neq 1$ 
$\alpha^{85} \bmod (x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1) \neq 1$ 
$\alpha^{255} \bmod (x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1) = 1$
(no need to test this case)

Exponentiation by squaring can be used to further speed up this process.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: I think the last exponent should be $255$. Even so, it is still possible that $\alpha$ would have order $51$ or $85$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Thanks, I update my answer.

Comment: Since $255 = 3\times 5\times 17$, it suffices to check $\alpha^{15}$, $\alpha^{51}$, $\alpha^{85}$, because e.g. $\alpha^3 = 1$ would imply $\alpha^{15} = 1$. Also no need to check $\alpha^{255}$. It's always $1$, as long as $\alpha$ is nonzero.

Comment: BTW, you can improve your answer further by [using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As you have been around for some time, it's probably a good idea to start learning how to use it.

Comment: @WhatsUp - most of my posts are at Stack Overflow, where MathJax isn't working, at least not in comments. I updated my answer here though.

Answer (score 3):

Pick an element and compute its powers. If these cover all nonzero elements, you have found a primitive element. Otherwise pick an element that you did not cover and start over again.

Comment: Is there a more efficient algorithm that works for all finite fields?

Comment: Actually, I guess it's not that bad. Averaged over the smallest 9700 prime powers $p^m$, the probability of picking a primitive element in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ is about 0.37.

Comment: You can directly go "by squares": take an element $\;a\in F\;,\;\;|F|=p^n\;$ , then it must be that $\;a^{\frac{p^n-1}2}=-1\;,\;\;a^k\neq 1\;\;\forall\,k<\frac{p^n-1}2\;$

Comment: This is very inefficient for anything but the smallest fields. Anyway, the problem is not straight forward.

Comment: Agree with @JyrkiLahtonen. Mathematically this is correct, but the efficiency is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Computationally, you can find it faster than "bruteforcing" (i.e. checking if all powers cover all elements). This is because you can quickly disregard a number from being a generator by checking if it generates a cycle smaller than required by the field. In other words, if $g^n \pmod p = g$ for  $n \in (2, p)$, $g$ is not a generator.

I'm not sure whether the fact that the cycle is not repeating necessarily makes it a generator, but this approach seemed to work for me so far. In fact, at least the opposite should be proven analytically, but I don't have that at hand at the moment and wanted to get this idea out there.

Comment: Exactly how are you proposing to check whether $g$ generates a smaller than a required cycle, if $p$ is, say, a 30-digit prime? Other than brute forcing the cycle, I mean.

Comment: Maybe I worded myself poorly, because this is essentially still brute force but allows you to disregard numbers quite fast.

Additional benefits are that you don't need to keep track of "visited" powers and (compared to this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/598498/1011297) reduces the number of iterations from $2p$ to $p$ because you don't need to check if all numbers from $(0, p)$ are in the set generated by $g^n \pmod p$.

I also programmed the above approach in a way that didn't require storing the numbers, but this meant that the number of iterations was $p^2$ for every $g$.